# Command line switch for custom zoom

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any command line switch or workaround for start chrome with some custom zoom?

Answer (score 9):

Scale to 1.5 times base setting using

`--force-device-scale-factor=1.5`

Other command line options can be found here:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: I'm using this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 --incognito and opens in incognito mode, but the zoom doesn't change, could be that I'm using chrome?

Comment: @user63227 I tested it on Arch Linux using `/usr/bin/chromium`, hence `—`. On Windows you‘d probably need to introduce the parameter differently e.g. `/force-device-scale-factor=1.5`.

Comment: I will try and will let you know, but the --incognito parameter works fine with the --

Comment: This is not the same as ctrl+ and ctrl-

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean always? Or sometimes (like from a particular shortcut on the desktop)?

You can set a default viewing zoom level in the **Chrome settings** page (chrome://chrome/settings/), by clicking on **Show advanced settings...**, and scrolling down to the  **Web content** section. This, however, will apply to every instance of Chrome, and not a single one as a command line option would.

Comment: from a shortcut in the desktop, I'm also adding the --incognito switch, so the chrome setting is not persistent between sessions

Comment: Hey, check this: [Zoom All](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcdohnadaogihannocnmahifljmhdkoe) Chrome extension. This solution may not be as elegant as a command line switch, but may very well work for you. You can enable it to work under Incognito in **Settings** -> **Extensions** -> **Allow in Incognito mode**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to temporarily set zoom for testing purposes you can set the zoom of the body in your css. That is essentially all chrome does anyway.

This would zoom the page to 50%.

```
body {
   zoom: .5;
}
```

Or if you want to do it for every page chrome opens you can change the default zoom in **Settings** click the **Show advanced settings...** link and look under the **Window Contents** section. This can be annoying though because every page you open will be effected.

Comment: Modifying body zoom is not the same as zooming in chrome. It messes up the layout of complex pages.

Answer (score 1):

I use tampermonkey to manage websites with zoom levels and other mods.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Netflix
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.netflix.com/*
// @match        http://www.netflix.com/*
// @grant        none
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Netflix');

jQuery('#hd').remove();
jQuery('title').html('Code Base');
jQuery( '<link rel="icon" href="demo_icon.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">' ).appendTo( "head" );
jQuery('body').css('zoom',.15);
```

Thanks Will for the zoom idea!!